# BinaryWrite two empty unicode characters after a string

Tags: c#, winforms, binarywriter

so i am trying to add two of 0x00 after every string i write in a binary file, these are what i tried(1 try per line), but i always end up having only one 0x00 after each string:

```
bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + '\0' + '\0'));
bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + "\0"));
bw.Write(enc.GetBytes(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text + (new string('\0', 2))));
```

but they all end up with the same result, is there another Unicode escape i can try to use ? or am i doing anything wrong in these lines ? and for an aside note, `String enc = Encoding.Unicode`

Comment: Focus on the code that reads this file.  It is bound to ignore the extra zeros, it is pretty common for such code to assume C string semantics.  Where a single 0 terminates the string.  Particularly so since such code could not use any other way to find out how many characters are in the string.  Use a hex viewer to gain confidence in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing should work. This test code demonstrates:

```
string test = "X" + '\0' + '\0';
Console.WriteLine(test.Length); // Prints 3
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(test);
Console.WriteLine(bytes.Length); // Prints 6
```

`bytes` contains the following byte values: `88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` - which is correct.

So I assume there's something wrong elsewhere with your code.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you, i know now where i was wrong, i don't really know how this works in SOF, so ill just post your answer and the Answer, thank you :)